# Does nvarchar always take twice as much space as varchar?

Tags: sql, database

Nvarchar is used to store unicode data which is used to store multilingual data. If you don't end up storing unicode does it still take up the same space?

Comment: I do believe that independet of the chars stored only one type of enconding will be used, so, it will take up space from unicode chars regardless of chars stored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YES.

See [MSDN Books Online on NCHAR and NVARCHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx).

**NCHAR:**

> The storage size is **two times n bytes.**

**NVARCHAR**

> The storage size, in bytes, is **two
>   times the number of characters** entered
>   + 2 bytes

Comment: Any idea how row/page compression affects this? `select cast(N'This is a test' as varbinary(20))` gives `0x5400680069007300200069007300200061002000`. In principle I would have thought those zeros could compress quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.  Not all unicode characters use two bytes.  Utf-8, for example, is still just one byte per character a lot of the time, but rarely you may need 4 bytes per character.  What nvarchar will do is *allocate* two bytes per character.

Comment: n(var)char columns use UCS-2, which is a 16-bit fixed-width encoding. It will always use exactly two bytes per character, even if one of those bytes is all zeros.